# How to display the output of a stored procedure in BigQuery which calls Apache Spark?

Tags: google-bigquery

I m trying the new "feature" of BigQuery, stored procedures for Apache Spark. At the end of the procedure, as per the example in [BQ documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/spark-procedures), there is the following lines:

> df.printSchema()

> df.show(truncate=False)

However nothing it is displayed.
Does anyone know how the output can be displayed in BigQeury WebUI or how it can be captured somehow?

Comment: could you confirm if no output is displayed after [calling](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/spark-procedures#call-spark-procedure) the procedure?

Comment: Yes, I cannot see any output, when for example at the end of the procedure, the line
df.show() is placed.